# Create own react route class in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I found this ([reacttraining.com](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/auth-workflow)) site, which explains react-router with some examples. But I am not be able to do this with a typescript class. What I want to do is extend the Route class to build my own one. Right now I want to implement it in typescript for authentication as in the following example from the site.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      React.createElement(component, props)
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

I searched a lot, but couldn't find a site that explains the function to implement and which typed properties to call to nested routes. An ES6 class will be also helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 20):

Here's my best shot so far, although there's still one `any` remaining :)

```
import * as React from "react"
import {Redirect, Route, RouteComponentProps, RouteProps} from "react-router-dom"

type RouteComponent = React.StatelessComponent<RouteComponentProps<{}>> | React.ComponentClass<any>

const AUTHENTICATED = false // TODO: implement authentication logic

export const PrivateRoute: React.StatelessComponent<RouteProps> = ({component, ...rest}) => {
  const renderFn = (Component?: RouteComponent) => (props: RouteProps) => {
    if (!Component) {
      return null
    }

    if (AUTHENTICATED) {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }

    const redirectProps = {
      to: {
        pathname: "/auth/sign-in",
        state: {from: props.location},
      },
    }

    return <Redirect {...redirectProps} />
  }

  return <Route {...rest} render={renderFn(component)} />
}
```

Comment: Thx for sharing your Solution! What would be the best way to use the PrivateRoute with components that have their own Properties?

Answer (score 10):

### Regarding Redux ...

[Jacka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441101/8089107) helped me alot, but i had a difficult time connecting the `PrivateRoute` component to redux. Furthermore i wanted to abstract the resulting `Route` component to work e.g. as a `LoggedInRoute`, `NotLoggedInRoute` or in general a `Route` which presents it's component if a condition is fulfilled or redirects to a specified location otherwise:

**Note:** Written with `redux` 4, `react-router-dom` 4 and typescript `2.9`.

```
import * as H from 'history';
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, MapStateToPropsParam } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect, Route, RouteComponentProps, RouteProps } from 'react-router';

export interface ConditionalRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  routeCondition: boolean;
  redirectTo: H.LocationDescriptor;
}

export class ConditionalRoute extends React.Component<ConditionalRouteProps> {
  public render() {
    // Extract RouteProps without component property to rest.
    const { component: Component, routeCondition, redirectTo, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <Route {...rest} render={this.renderFn} />
  }

  private renderFn = (renderProps: RouteComponentProps<any>) => {
    if (this.props.routeCondition) {
      const { component: Component } = this.props; // JSX accepts only upprcase.
      if (!Component) {
        return null;
      }
      return <Component {...renderProps} />
    }

    return <Redirect to={this.props.redirectTo} />;
  };
}

export function connectConditionalRoute<S>(mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<ConditionalRouteProps, RouteProps, S>) {
  return connect<ConditionalRouteProps, {}, RouteProps, S>(mapStateToProps)(ConditionalRoute);
}
```

You can either use the `ConditionalRoute` component without connecting it and use your component's local state, e.g.:

```
interface RootState {
  loggedIn: boolean;
}

export class Root extends React.Component<RootProps, RootState> {
  /* skipped initialState and setState(...) calls */

  public render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <ConditionalRoute
          path="/todos"
          component={TodoPage}
          routeCondition={this.state.loggedIn}
          redirectTo="/login" />
        <ConditionalRoute
          path="/login"
          component={LoginPage}
          routeCondition={!this.state.loggedIn}
          redirectTo="/" />
        <Redirect to="/todos" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Or use the utility function `connectConditionalRoute<S>(...)` to use your redux store:

```
const loginRoute = '/login';
const todosRoute = '/todos';

const LoggedInRoute = connectConditionalRoute<RootState>(state => ({
  redirectTo: loginRoute,
  routeCondition: state.isLoggedIn,
}));

const NotLoggedInRoute = connectConditionalRoute<RootState>(state => ({
  redirectTo: todosRoute,
  routeCondition: !state.isLoggedIn
}));

const Root: React.SFC = () => (
  <Switch>
    <LoggedInRoute path="/todos" component={TodoPage} />
    <NotLoggedInRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Redirect to="/todos" />
  </Switch>
);
```

The behaviour in the provided sample: Unauthorized users visit `/todos`, get redirected to `/login`, authorized users visit `/login`, get redirected to `/todos`. Whenever the redux store's `isLoggedIn` changes, the connected components are updated and redirect the user automatically.

Answer (score 6):

here is my solution using `"react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.6"` and `"typescript": "3.2.2"`

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import {
  Route, 
  Redirect,
  RouteProps, 
  RouteComponentProps
} from "react-router-dom";

interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  component:
    | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>
    | React.ComponentType<any>;
}

const PrivateRoute: FunctionComponent<PrivateRouteProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        true ? ( //put your authenticate logic here
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/signin"
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `any`.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest }: any) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={PrivateRender(Component)} />
);

const PrivateRender = (Component: any) => {
  return (props: any) => {
    return <Component {...props}/>;
  };
};
```

Comment: using any is just shutting the linter down, but not giving the static typing benefits like autocomplete/intellisense/error before app is run.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for same thing. The question is old but maybe someone is still looking for it.
Here is what I come up with (All types properly used from react-router 4):

```
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  component: React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>> | React.ComponentType<any>
}
type RenderComponent = (props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => React.ReactNode;

export class PrivateRoute extends Route<PrivateRouteProps> {
  render () {
    const {component: Component, ...rest}: PrivateRouteProps = this.props;
    const renderComponent: RenderComponent = (props) => (
      AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated()
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
    );

    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={renderComponent} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: +uno for using types properly in a concise solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really simple way to do this using function components since the new react router version allows you to access everything through hooks:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Redirect, Route, RouteProps} from 'react-router-dom'

const PrivateRoute = (props: RouteProps) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useYourSessionProviderContext()
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Route {...props} />
  } else {
    return <Redirect to='/login' />
  }
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed here didn't work for me because I was using both `component` and `render` params in my original Routes. In this solution you can use any configuration of Route in your custom PrivateRoute instead of only the `component` param.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Route, 
    Redirect,
    RouteProps,
    RouteComponentProps
} from "react-router-dom";

interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
}

export class PrivateRoute extends Route<PrivateRouteProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route render={(props: RouteComponentProps) => {
                if(!this.props.isAuthenticated()) {
                    return <Redirect to='/login' />
                } 

                if(this.props.component) {
                    return React.createElement(this.props.component);
                } 

                if(this.props.render) {
                    return this.props.render(props);
                }
            }} />
        );
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
<PrivateRoute 
    path={'/dashboard'} 
    component={DashboardPage} 
    isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated}
/>
<PrivateRoute 
    path={'/checkout'} 
    isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated}
    render={() => (
       <CheckoutPage auth={props.auth} />
    )} 
/>
```

Comment: Attempting to use this but it never executes the redirect, always renders the component. When at a breakpoint on the return I can see that this.props.isAuthenticated is false yet it still renders the component.

Comment: Also seeing this `Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route render> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored`

Comment: Good catch. I revised my solution.