# programatically send a user to login page in react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using react.js with redux and react-connected-router to build a frontend application.

The auth flow is the following:

- login page is being displayed
- login successful, token is saved to redux store
- If a user gets logged out for whatever reason, the token is deleted from the store
- If no token is in the store the user should see the login page

I know I should use `{push} from 'connected-react-router'` to push the user to `/login`

However it seems like I cannot use `store.subscribe()` in a component that is a child to `<Provider store={store}>`.

Unfortunately I can only use `push()` in a child of `<ConnectedRouter history={history}>`, which itself is a child to `<Provider store={store}>`

Therefore my Question is: **How and where in my application can I detect the deletion of the token and redirect to `/login`?**

Comment: I can image the flow beeing like this: On user login you dispatch a appropriate action, setting the auth token. Because of the state update, connected components re-render when they map the auth-token in `mapStateToProps`, this way you could return a `<Redirect />` component in your render method, which results in your desired behaviour. This works for logout actions the same way. Another approach is to use [redux thunk](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-navigate-with-redux-action) and dispatch multiple actions.

Comment: then for every component token has to be mapped @sn42

Comment: If at any instant the token is not available you want to move to login page. In the route component where you define all the route you can check whether token is available or not if available no problem and if not then move to login page now I think this place is sufficient to write what @sn42 has mentioned

Comment: route component remains active throughout app runs. so only one place in needed for auth

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala Just to recap for other readers (your argumentation is a bit jumpy): Only selected components need to map to the auth token in the state: The component responsible for redirecting and any component who neeeds info about whether the user is authenticated (e.g. username in navigation, etc). If there are additional side-effects libraries for asynchronous actions are helpful.

Comment: I am not a pro so it may be.. but I have tried a kinda same thing in my project where I used concept of private route and public route mixed with what I said. And my project is working superb. check: https://github.com/shabyWoks/shabywoks

Comment: You need to create a component as a manipulated route to use for Auth-required route. If you need more information, let me know, so I'll write a full answer

Comment: If you are interested in solving this with plain `react-router` (history not handled in redux) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458206/8089107

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I posted an answer using `<Redirect\>` and `connect()` to redirect and fetch states. You may please post another answer or edit mine if there's a more elegant approach available or if I misunderstood your advices (because I at least didn't fully understood them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using below approach, where I subscribe to `apiKey` and `router` states and use them to redirect to `/login` if needed using `react-router`s `<Redirect\>` component.

All done in the routing component which is child to the above mentioned components `<ConnectedRouter history={history}>` and  `<Provider store={store}>`.

Therefore theres o need to use `store.subscribe()` directly anymore. Also `push` is replaced by the `<Redirect\>` component.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    apiKey: state.apiKey,
    router: state.router
});

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        let redirectToLogin;
        console.log(this.props.router.location.pathname)
        if (this.props.apiKey.role === "other" && this.props.router.location.pathname !== "/login") {
            redirectToLogin = <Redirect to="/login"/>
        } else {
            redirectToLogin = ""
        }

        return (
            <main>
                {redirectToLogin}
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
                    <Route exact path='/somepage' component={SomePage}/>
                </Switch>
            </main>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Main))
```